# Como generar en python un pdf desde mysql

Tags: python-3.x, mysqli, flask

estoy usando python flask y quiero generar un reporte en pdf desde una tabla de mi base mysql e intentado hacer lo siguiente pero el pdf me sale sin los datos si alguien puede decirme como hacerlo se los agradeceria mucho

```
    pdf = FPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4')
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font('Times', 'B', 12)
    pdf.set_fill_color(0, 0, 255)
    pdf.cell(190, 10, "REPORTE GENERAL DE ASISTENCIAS",10, 25,"C")
    # Se agrega otra celda próxima a la anterior pero con texto centrado
    #DATOS DEL ENCABEZADO DE LA BITACORA
    pdf.cell(8, 10, "ID", 1, 0)
    pdf.cell(50, 10, ("ALUMNO"), 1, 0)
    pdf.cell(45, 10, "CLASE", 1, 0)
    pdf.cell(30, 10, "FECHA", 1, 0)
    pdf.cell(30, 10, ("ASISTENCIA"), 1, 0)
    pdf.cell(20, 10, "FALTAS", 1, 1)

    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT `idasistencias`, `faltas`, `asistencia`,asistencias.fecha, alumnos.nombres,alumnos.apellidos, clases.nombre_clase FROM `asistencias` INNER JOIN alumnos ON alumnos_idalumnos = alumnos.idalumnos INNER JOIN clases ON clases_idclases = clases.idclases ORDER BY idasistencias ASC")
    resultado = cursor.fetchall() 

    for registro in resultado:
        nombre = registro[0] 
        apellido = registro[1] 
        edad = registro[2] 
        sexo = registro[3] 
        salario = registro[4] 
    # Imprimimos los resultados obtenidos 
    # print "nombre=%s, apellido=%s, edad=%d, sexo=%s, salario=%d" % (nombre, apellido, edad, sexo, salario)
        pdf.cell(8, 10,"", 1, 0)
        pdf.cell(50, 10,"apellido=%s" % (apellido,), 1, 0)
        pdf.cell(45, 10,"nombre=%s" % (nombre) , 1, 0)
        pdf.cell(30, 10,"nombre_clase" , 1, 0)
        pdf.cell(30, 10, "nombre_clase", 1, 0)
        pdf.cell(20, 10, "nombre_clase", 1, 1)

        pdf.output(name = "reporte_asistencias2.pdf",dest='F')
```

el pdf me genera asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque escribes 3 veces ´nombre_clase´ dentro del ´for´

Comment: la parte de nombre clase fue solo porque queria probar que si se generaba el pdf pero al momento de mandar a imprimir las filas no me sale si alguien tiene una idea de como hacerlo

Comment: Cuando imprimes los resultados obtenidos, cuantos registros te muestra?

Comment: como puedes ver en la imagen no me muestra ningun registro de mi base de datos no se como debo imprimir los row  al momento que mando a imprimir  'pdf.cell(45, 10,registro[0] , 1, 0)' me genera este error  **AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'**

Comment: Me refiero al `print` que tienes comentado

Comment: ese print estado probando algunas opciones para ver si imprimia en el pdf pero no imprime por eso lo comente

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo si te esta mostrando los datos correctamente. Entiendo que `registro[0] = idasistencias` y `registro[1] = faltas`.

Por lo que `registro[4] = alumnos.nombres` y `registro[5] = alumnos.apellidos` seria los datos que quieres ver.